# Can't Get a Virtual Host to Work

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I can't get a specific virtual host to work. This is the first part of my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Data RAID/htdocs/Symfony/web"
    ServerName framework.loc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Data RAID/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Data RAID/htdocs/AmColAn"
    ServerName amcolan.loc
</VirtualHost>
```

It's the first one that fails. The others work fine.
I can get to index.php using:

```
http://localhost/symfony/web/index.php
```

I can't get to it using:

```
http://framework.loc/index.php
```

I get redirected to OpenDNS, which I use as my DNS, with the error that it is not loading. This is on OS X 10.8.2. I restart apache every time I change the config.  I must be making some sort of bonehead error.

Comment: This sounds like you haven't set the appropriate entry in your DNS (HOSTS) file? But you suggest the last one (amcolan.loc) is working OK?

Comment: Yes, amcolan.loc works as well as several others in the same format I didn't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, an appropriate entry needs to also be set in DNS (ie. local HOSTS file) that *points* the domain `framework.loc` to the webserver.

For example:

```
127.0.0.1  framework.loc
```

This appears to have been missing/incorrect in this instance.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the hosts file. If I don't do things like this on a regulars basis, I forget some of the steps.